# Unable to navigate to screen with React Native Navigation

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm having trouble with React Navigation on React Native Expo.

I have a bottom tab navigator, a separate screen (ProfileScreen), and a modal (ProfileLoginModal). The modal has a button that should redirect ProfileScreen. I put `navigation.navigate("ProfileScreen")` in the modal, but it's not doing anything, it's not even giving me an error.

But if I change it to one of the screens in the bottom tab nav, for example `navigation.navigate("Root", {screen: "HomeScreen})`, it works just fine. It just doesn't work with screens outside the bottom tab nav.

Can anyone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Navigation structure:

```
- BottomTabNavigator (Root)
   - HomeScreen
   - MenuScreen
- ProfileScreen
- ProfileLoginModal
```

Here is my navigation:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

<NavigationContainer linking={LinkingConfiguration}>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Root"
      component={BottomTabNavigator}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="ProfileScreen"        // ProfileScreen (destination)
      component={ProfileScreen}
    />
    <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ProfileLoginModal"    // Go to ProfileScreen from this modal
        component={ProfileLoginModal}
       />
    </Stack.Group>
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>


const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator<RootTabParamList>();

function BottomTabNavigator() {
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
      screenOptions={...}
    >
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={...}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Menu"
        component={MenuScreen}
        options={...}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Typings:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Root: NavigatorScreenParams<RootTabParamList> | undefined;
  ProfileScreen: undefined;
  ProfileLoginModal: undefined;
};

export type RootStackScreenProps<Screen extends keyof RootStackParamList> =
  NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, Screen>;

export type RootTabParamList = {
  HomeScreen: undefined;
  MenuScreen: undefined;
};

export type RootTabScreenProps<Screen extends keyof RootTabParamList> =
  CompositeScreenProps<
    BottomTabScreenProps<RootTabParamList, Screen>,
    NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>
  >;
```

Extra detail: I'd like ProfileScreen to have the bottom tab navigator visible, but with no corresponding tab icon.

I tried to make a nested navigator containing HomeScreen and ProfileScreen, like this

```
- BottomTabNavigator (Root)
   - NestedHome
      - HomeScreen
      - ProfileScreen
   - MenuScreen
- ProfileLoginModal
```

But I had a lot of issues as I didn't know how to access double nested screens, if even possible (`navigation.navigate('Root', screen: {'NestedHome', screen: {'ProfileScreen'}})` is clearly incorrect). I couldn't find much info about it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going for the nested navigation that I tried before. The right function is `navigation.navigate("Root", {screen: "NestedHome", params: {screen: "ProfileScreen"}})`. From what I've seen, the docs don't go into details on this, and I only found out through a different SO thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
- BottomTabNavigator (Root)
   - NestedHome
      - HomeScreen
      - ProfileScreen
   - MenuScreen
- ProfileLoginModal
```

From HomeScreen you can navigate to ProfileScreen without nesting params :

```
navigation.navigate("ProfileScreen")
```

ProfileLoginModal knows only about Root screen - if you want to navigate from ProfileLoginModal to ProfileScreen you need to use nesting params

```
navigation.navigate("Root", { 
  screen: "NestedHome", 
  params: { 
    screen: "ProfileScreen"
  }
})
```

You can access deep nested screens by specifying a params key

```
 navigation.navigate("Root", { 
      screen: "NestedHome", 
      params: { 
        screen: "ProfileScreen"
        params: {
          screen: 'DeepNestedScreen'
        }
      }
    })
```